# GetGlobalContext is not defined in HTML webresrouce of Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm, webresource

I've an HTML web resource in Dynamics CRM on-premise environment. It is saved as `new_htmlpage1`, now at a click of Custom button I'm opening this `HTML` web resource. I've added `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` as reference in HTML webresource as well. But still I am receiving error that `GetGlobalContext is not defined`

Below is my HTML source code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function tempContext(){

 if (typeof GetGlobalContext != "undefined") {

            var userName = Xrm.Page.context.getUserName();

            alert(userName);

            return;

        }

}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="tempContext()">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the walkthrough from Microsoft that I am following, but still unable to get GlobalContext.

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: try this way <script src="clientGlobalcontext.js.aspx"></script>

Comment: I tried with this approach as well, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

The path to `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx` is a relative path (relative to the location of your web resource), so ensure that you navigate up the necessary amount of times. E.g. one of the following might be what you need to use, depending on your web resource:

```
<script src="ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="../../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

You should then call the function `GetGlobalContext()` from JavaScript to get access to the global context.

Right now you are trying to call `Xrm.*`, which is not available. 
As the [documentation for the GetGlobalContext function](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/GetGlobalContext-ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx) states:

> Including a reference to **ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx** does not make the
>   **Xrm** object available in HTML web resources. Therefore, scripts
>   containing `Xrm.*` methods aren’t supported in HTML web resources.
>   `parent.Xrm.*` will work if the HTML web resource is loaded in a form
>   container. However, for other places, such as loading an HTML web
>   resource as part of the SiteMap, `parent.Xrm.*` also won’t work.

Comment: I just wanted to illustrate that it is relative to the path of your web resource. What do you mean that it is not working? What is the path to your web resource? Can you see in developer console whether the file is loaded or not?

Comment: I mean all three formats don't worked for me. I've also checked in Console and the file ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx is not loading.

Comment: Great, then you know that you still need to properly load `ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx`. You can get back to me once you have that working. You will need to navigate up from the location of your web resource, which is why I have been asking you about what the path to your web resource is.

Comment: my webresource path is `http://<domain>/<organization>/WebResources/new_documentuploader`